# Huffman code tree decoding

Tags: java, huffman-code

I'm trying to decode a huffmann binary code tree with no success. Am using the following code:

```
public static int decodeTree(String str){
    int length = str.length();
    int num = 0;
    int number = 0;
    Node root = tree1.get(0);
    String b;
    // 0 left
    // 1 right
    for (int x = 0; x <tree1.size(); x++) {
      Node curr = root;
      while ((curr.isLeaf() == false) && num < length) {
        if (str.charAt(num) == '0') {
          curr = curr.Left();
          num++;
        }
        else if (str.charAt(num) == '1') { 
          curr = curr.Right();
          num++;
        }
      }

      number = curr.getValue();
    }

    return number;
}
```

It should output:

`10,  46, 200, 155, 50, 50, 23, 12, 18, 59,  40, 10,  200, 10, 40,  50, 46, 12, 18, 200, 46`

It is currently outputting:

`155, 46, 200, 200, 50, 91, 23, 12, 46, 200, 40, 200, 155, 50, 200, 68, 38, 50, 18, 200, 200`

It is to return decimal numbers. It decodes some numbers correctly but in the wrong sequence. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

I'm also uploading my Tree implementation:

```
public static String[] huffman(int[] histo){
    //initial list of nodes
        tree1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < histo.length; i++)
        if(histo[i] != 0) {
            tree1.add(new Node(histo[i], i));
        }

    //get weights until only root node is left out
    while(tree1.size() > 1){
        combine(tree1);
    }

    //recursively generate code for each node in the tree
    //if the recursion finds a leaf node,
    //it sets the correct element in the array to the code of the node
    Node root = tree1.get(0);
    String[] codage = new String[histo.length];
    root.genCodeWord(codage);

    return codage;
}
```

Further information:

This is how I'm trying to decode back:

```
String[] oneDConvertedBack1 = new String[oneD.length];
System.out.print("\n\nCONVERTED BACK:\n");
for(int i =0; i<oneD.length; i++)
    Gray graycode = new Gray();
    oneDConvertedBack1[i] = graycode.convertToBinaryCode(oneDGray[i]);
}
for(int i=0; i<oneD.length;i++)
    System.out.print(oneDConvertedBack1[i]+ ", ");

int[] oneDConvertedBack2 = new int[oneD.length];
System.out.print("\n\nCONVERTED BACK:\n");
for(int i =0; i<oneD.length; i++) {
    oneDConvertedBack2[i] = decodeTree(oneDBinary[i]);
}
```

The following are the constituents of the Nodes of the tree and its CodeWord method

```
public Node(Node left, Node right, int value){
    l = left;
    r = right;
    v = value;
    i = -1;
}

public void genCodeWord(String[] codes){

    if(l != null && r != null){
        l.setCodeWord("0"+getCodeWord());
        l.genCodeWord(codes);
        r.setCodeWord("1"+getCodeWord());
        r.genCodeWord(codes);
    }else{
        codes[i] = getCodeWord();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an example and point out what is wrong and what would be correct.

Comment: It should output: 10,46,200,155,50,50,23,12,18,59,40,10,200,10,40,50,46,12,18,200,46It is currently outputting as follows: 155, 46, 200, 200, 50, 91, 23, 12, 46, 200, 40, 200, 155, 50, 200, 68, 38, 50, 18, 200, 200

Comment: Now all that is missing is your tree

Comment: added the tree to the above

Comment: I still dont see an answer, please create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: done as requested